# Assigning colors in highchart base on the result of javascript

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to assign the color of highchart base on the return value of javascript

Here is my code...

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},

series: [{
    name: 'John',
    color: '#EDF249',/*(function() {
            return '#EDF249';
        }),*/
    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
        [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5], 
        [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
    ]
},{
    name: 'Mary',
    color: '#FF0000',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 60.9], 
        [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1), 40.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 90.0], 
        [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 80.4]
    ]
}]
});
```

if I will directly assign the color it will work but if I will assign the color base on the return value of javascript it's not working... any help

Comment: because a `function` is not a valid value for `color`. You need to call the function separately and assign the value

Comment: Hi @musefan yes your right I realize that after I post this question..Thanks a lot. I have another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767540/how-to-change-the-highchart-color-dynamically/14772259#14772259 do you have any idea on how to solve this question

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from musefan, just call the function you have there:

```
color: (function() {
    return '#EDF249';
})(), //the last () calls the function
```

Comment: Just call the separate function you created instead of calling the function(){}.....